# How to get unique parts number with their brands in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have below tables in my database, I want to get unique part numbers and with their brand name. 
All these below tables are based on EAV Model

**Table 1 for Part number (for ex - 8004).**

**entity_id** is unique constraint

```
select * from catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id = 961 and value = '8004';
```

`+-----------+----------------+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+
| value_id  | entity_type_id | attribute_id | store_id | entity_id | value |
+-----------+----------------+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+
|  19507400 |             10 |          961 |        0 |     39214 | 8004  |
|  19507401 |             10 |          961 |        0 |    281155 | 8004  |
|  19507402 |             10 |          961 |        0 |   1926249 | 8004  |
|  64825324 |             10 |          961 |        0 |  11892287 | 8004  |
| 168417193 |             10 |          961 |        0 |  22721887 | 8004  |
+-----------+----------------+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+`

**Table 2 for Brand Code -**

```
select * from catalog_product_entity_int where attribute_id = 953 and entity_id in (39214,281155,1926249,11892287,22721887);
```

`+----------+----------------+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+
| value_id | entity_type_id | attribute_id | store_id | entity_id | value |
+----------+----------------+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+
|  5401700 |             10 |          953 |        0 |     39214 |  1050 |
|  5401701 |             10 |          953 |        0 |    281155 |  1109 |
|  5401702 |             10 |          953 |        0 |   1926249 |  1082 |
| 21106883 |             10 |          953 |        0 |  11892287 |  1109 |
| 87135500 |             10 |          953 |        0 |  22721887 |  1109 |
+----------+----------------+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+`

**Table 3 for actual brand name based on brand codes.**

```
select * from eav_attribute_option_value where option_id in (1050,1109,1082);
```

`+----------+-----------+----------+------------------------+
| value_id | option_id | store_id | value                  |
+----------+-----------+----------+------------------------+
|    15222 |      1050 |        0 | Samsung                |
|    13070 |      1082 |        0 | Whirlpool              |
|    15317 |      1109 |        0 | GE                     |
+----------+-----------+----------+------------------------+`

**Expected Output -**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the query you are looking for

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(b.entity_id SEPARATOR ',') as entity_ids,p.value as part_no,GROUP_CONCAT(b.value SEPARATOR ',') as brand_code, GROUP_CONCAT(bn.value SEPARATOR ',') as brand_name FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar p RIGHT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int b ON p.entity_id  = b.entity_id  LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_option_value bn ON b.value = bn.option_id WHERE p.attribute_id = '961' GROUP BY b.entity_type_id
```

Comment: no this is not working. entity_type_id  and entity_id are different.

Comment: will attribute_id act as foreign key in first 2 tables?